# How can I swap the left alt key and left win key for LXM-00001 (Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard) in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, swap

I can swap other keys in this environment, well. But the only left win key can not be changed to any keys. How can I change the left win key to an other key?

Xkb and Xmode is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this should be okay. It's simple to change the value. It will do.

`# vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`

```
<LALT> = 133;
...
<LWIN> = 64;
```

Don't forget to keep the original file.

Comment: Correct!! It is the option for the microsoft keyboards. Thank you!